# Button label color change doesn't work if font is also changed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ibdesignable

Here is a simple example custom button that is set as a class of a button in IB:

```
#import "TestButton.h"
@implementation TestButton

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8];
    if ( self.setFont )
        self.titleLabel.font = font;
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

If setFont is false, that is, the font is unchanged, the the label text color is red as expected.  But if it is true, the button text color is whatever it is set to in IB.

So the question is what's going on here, and how can I change both the text and the font of a button that is assigned in IB programmatically.

In case someone wants to see these peculiarities and also how funky IBDesignable can be, see [demo project](https://github.com/etcetc/ButtonTitleColorIssue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

with

```
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks - this works.  Interesting that when using IB_DESIGNABLE and IBInspectable on setFont in xCode 6.2, it does the opposite.  That is, when I set the font to off, it updates the title color as expected but when on, text stays default color, not red.  In any case, would you know why setting the color of the titleLabel doesn't work?

Comment: I'm personally not sure why Apple doesn't allow the first method to work, but I do know that the second method is better because it allows you to set the colors for multiple states in addition to `UIControlStateNormal`. (for example, you can use `UIControlStateHighlighted` to define what color to make the text when the button is clicked)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is for setting text:

```
[self setTitle:@"New Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you wanted to set the title or the color of the title anywhere other than within the button file itself, you could try adding two public properties to the button. One NSString property for the title (self.titleString) and one UIColor property for the title color. You could then set the title and or title color anywhere like in your view controller or view. You would then use these properties within your button file like

```
[self setTitle:self.titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```